# android - using new thread in ViewModel class

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I am using data mvvm architecture in my android app and filling xml item with data binding. in view model class I use `AsyncTask` for get data from database and this  makes me some trouble. UI thread is called first and my xml items remains empty. what must I do?

Comment: can you share your code of **AsyncTask** ?

Comment: thank you jeel, I find my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find my solution. I just put `notifyPropertyChanged(BR.item);` after filling my item and `@Bindable` before getMethod